# Why does NDSolve work with an initial condition but not a final condition?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am using NDSolve to solve the two-dimensional time-dependent (2+1D) Schroedinger equation for a traveling gaussian wavepacket in free space. The exact solution is:

```
psi[x_, y_, t_] := (
4 E^(I (25 - t/2 + x) - ((25 - t + x)^2 + y^2)/(64 + 2 I t)) Sqrt[
2/\[Pi]])/(32 + I t)
```

Which at t=0 looks like:

[image]

If I specify only the initial conditions at t=0: psin[x,y,0]=psi[x,y,0], NDSolve works fine:

```
NDSolve[{I D[psin[x, y, t], {t, 1}] + 1/2 D[psin[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + 
1/2 D[psin[x, y, t], {y, 2}] == 0, psin[x, y, 0] == psi[x, y, 0], 
psin[-100, y, t] == 0, psin[100, y, t] == 0, psin[x, -100, t] == 0, 
psin[x, 100, t] == 0}, psin, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {t, 0, 
50}, MaxStepSize -> 1]
```

Which at t=0 looks like:

[image]

But if I instead give only the final condition at t=50: psin[x,y,50]=psi[x,y,50], NDSolve does not work:

```
NDSolve[{I D[psin[x, y, t], {t, 1}] + 1/2 D[psin[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + 
1/2 D[psin[x, y, t], {y, 2}] == 0, 
psin[x, y, 50] == psi[x, y, 50], psin[-100, y, t] == 0, 
psin[100, y, t] == 0, psin[x, -100, t] == 0, 
psin[x, 100, t] == 0}, psin, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, {t, 0, 
50}, MaxStepSize -> 1]

NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 
84.65891274149153` at t = 0.` in the direction of independent variable x is 
much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 200 points 
may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity 
may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the 
MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.
```

Which at t=0 looks like:

[image]

Why does NDSolve work with an initial condition but not a final condition? What can be done to get NDSolve to work with a final condition?

Comment: try a change of variable `tprime=50-t` so then `NDSolve` will see your condition as an initial condition.

Comment: Can you please explain the details?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with inconsistent conditions.  Look at

```
psi[-70, y, 0] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[70, y, 0] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[x, -40, 0] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[x, 40, 0] // N // Simplify // Chop
```

The results are all 0 under a Chop, so that they match within tolerances the set bc's.  However

```
psi[-70, y, 50] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[70, y, 50] // Simplify // Chop
psi[x, -40, 50] // N // Simplify // Chop
psi[x, 40, 50] // N // Simplify // Chop
```

results in

```
0
(-6.11209*10^-7 + 5.43003*10^-6 I) E^((-0.0045403 + 0.00709421 I) y^2)
(-0.0000226642 - 0.0000300422 I) 2.71828^((0. + 1. I) x - (0.0045403 - 
     0.00709421 I) (x - 25.)^2)
(-0.0000226642 - 0.0000300422 I) 2.71828^((0. + 1. I) x - (0.0045403 - 
     0.00709421 I) (x - 25.)^2)
```

Your other conditions require these values of x and y be 0 for all t.  The conditions are near enough to 0 at t = 0, but not near enough to 0 at t = 50, so that NDSolve experiences instability when you use the end condition.

Comment: I fixed the boundary conditions so they are consistent, but it did not fix the problem. I revised the question to include the new boundary conditions.

Comment: I tried with WorkingPrecision->50 and still get the warnings except for the inconsistent bc warning.  It takes forever, but behavior along y = 0 for x from -100 to about +50 looks fairly close to psi.  At x > 50 still blows up.  Higher WP probably will not help much and will be too slow.   It was the higher WP that alerted me to the inconstent bc's in your original problem.